# dbt found two resources with the database representation

Tags: sql, dbt

I have two .sql dbt models `models/A/claim.sql` and `models/A/prod_claim.sql`.

My goal is to create claim table in two different db/schema that is mentioned in the `profiles.yaml` as different targets.

They have different tags mentioned in the `schema.yaml` file.

[image: prod_claim schema]
[image: claim schema]

```
dbt compile --profile stage --target prod --select tag:prod
11:11:20  Running with dbt=1.5.3
11:11:21  Registered adapter: snowflake=1.5.2
11:11:21  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error
  dbt found two resources with the database representation "A.V.claim".
  dbt cannot create two resources with identical database representations. To fix this,
  change the configuration of one of these resources:
  - model.r.claim (models/l/raw/claim.sql)
  - model.r.prod_claim (models/l/prod/prod_claim.sql)
```

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.